# Does robocopy make a local copy of the files?

Tags: windows-server-2008, nas, robocopy

I have a seagate NAS which I access over a shared folder. I also have 3 computers with a shared folder.
I want to backup files from the 3 computers to the seagate NAS. I cannot run those tasks with the seagate NAS itself so I want to do it from a 3rd Windows Server I have running.
If I tell my Windows server to copy the files from the 3 computers to the NAS (With robocopy) will it be slower, because it copies from "shared folder on computer 1,2,3" -> Windows Server -> NAS or does it copy it directly?
I hope my question is clear enough for someone to answer...

Comment: It will use the server as the intermediary and flow the copy through it, yes.  But not keep a copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The files will go through the Windows Server box in the middle, but the server won't store a copy of the files, it happens in-memory. You can verify this by looking the the network throughput of the server while doing copying (that is, if the server isn't doing much else besides the file copy).

Comment: Ok so that means it will be a little slower than copying it directly? Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: Depends, not necessarily. If it's a slow NAS for instance, that could be a bottleneck.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So I will try to make it work another way... I have the feeling that there are just too many possible bottlenecks.